# output tag needs some community input

Tags: discussion, tags

The [output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/output) has 149 questions tagged across wide range of topics - command line output, audio output, monitors - and no wiki nor usage guidance as to what this tag is all about. We already have specialized tags for all those topics, in particular [stdout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/stdout), [display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/display), [sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sound). Maybe we could get rid of this one ?

Comment: I thought exactly that when I stumbled across it yesterday, you beat me to the meta question. :)

Comment: Oh wow, that's the very definition of a useless tag, yes.

Answer (score 11):

#### Let’s burminate it!

(but I need 30 chars here)

Comment: Isn’t that spelled “[burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/195817)”?